# How to conditionally select an aggregate function return value?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, aggregate-functions, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

Currently I'm asking min and max values like this:

```
$query = $query
    ->where(['date >=' => $today])
    ->select([
        'minvalue' => $this->Daten->find()->func()->min('brennstoff'),
        'maxvalue' => $this->Daten->find()->func()->max('brennstoff')
    ])
    ->hydrate(false)
    ->toArray();
```

Sometimes the min or maxvalues could be `NULL`, so there will be no result; but I want to have `0` (zero) to be given out.

In SQL I'd use `IF(MIN(value), MIN(value), 0))`. But how to translate this in the ORM syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IF` is very MySQL specific, I'd suggest using a `CASE` expression instead, which is understood by all SQL dialects that are supported by CakePHP.

While the query builder can be used to create any type of SQL function call by simply calling a magic method with the same name via the functions builder, like:

```
$minValue = $query->func()->IF([
    $query->newExpr()->isNotNull($query->func()->min('brennstoff')),
    $query->func()->min('brennstoff'),
    0
]);

$maxValue = $query->func()->IF([
    $query->newExpr()->isNotNull($query->func()->max('brennstoff')),
    $query->func()->max('brennstoff'),
    0
]);
```

or `IFNULL` for something more compact:

```
$minValue = $query->func()->IFNULL([
    $query->func()->min('brennstoff'),
    0
]);

$maxValue = $query->func()->IFNULL([
    $query->func()->max('brennstoff'),
    0
]);
```

there are concrete helper methods for `CASE` expressions:

```
$minValue = $query
    ->newExpr()
    ->addCase(
        [$query->newExpr()->isNotNull($query->func()->min('brennstoff'))],
        [$query->func()->min('brennstoff'), 0],
        [null, 'integer']
    );

$maxValue = $query
    ->newExpr()
    ->addCase(
        [$query->newExpr()->isNotNull($query->func()->max('brennstoff'))],
        [$query->func()->max('brennstoff'), 0],
        [null, 'integer']
    );

$query = $query
    ->select([
        'minvalue' => $minValue,
        'maxvalue' => $maxValue
    ])
    // ...
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Case statements](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#case-statements)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using SQL Functions](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions)**
- **[MySQL Reference Manual / Functions and Operators / Control Flow Functions > CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)**